# Rails structure folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner of RAILS.

I wrote some code , which validate if the cvs I load is correct

I have also a controller Employee (in this controller I will put validation) :

```
def import
  if params[:csv_file]
    Employee.import_from_csv(params[:csv_file], @organization, current_user)
    redirect_to admin_organization_employees_path(@organization), :notice => "Your request has been accepted! We will inform you via email about the results!"
  else
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Missing file"
  end
end
```

In which place  should I put Class CSV_Validator which has lots of code?? In Lib how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

In your model.

Just as rule of thumb, place the bulk of your code in models.

[Rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-model)